# Clipping raster data without losing resolution?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip, resolution

How can I clip high-resolution raster data in ArcMap without losing resolution?

Comment: What precisely have you tried?  What were the results?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "environment" button at the bottom of each tool. In the environment settings, go to raster analysis and select "minimum of input" as a pixel size. If you work with arcpy, you can set the environment with arcpy.env